# Creating unique background in css, image insed

Tags: css, background

Is there a way to create a background like so in css? I didn't know how to describe it so google coudn't help me. Thanks!

[image: desired background]

Comment: Not sure with css maybe a clever trickery of css3, but you can use javascript and canvas for sure

Comment: Here are some examples http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

Comment: "Sunburst" is one name I've seen given for that type of pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do it with an SVG image, but be aware that the support could be spotty. It would probably be easier to just create it in Photoshop or GIMP and make it really big (say 1620x1080)

A quick search on CSS and SVG backgrounds came up with this [page](http://helephant.com/2009/08/12/svg-images-as-css-backgrounds/); but it's from 2009.

Comment: As far as desktop browsers go, IE 8 and older is the only one you have to worry about not supporting SVG background images.  Fallback can be found here:  http://www.broken-links.com/2010/06/14/using-svg-in-backgrounds-with-png-fallback/